# Bootstrap 5 Vertical Alignment Bottom

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

please refer to the following codes:

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p class="ms-auto small">Stupid Text</p>
</div>
<hr class="my-0">
```

I am trying to make the "Stupid Text" vertical align at bottom near to the line, I have tried "align-items-bottom", "align-bottom", "align-text-bottom" but it just dont move.

Any idea how to fix this using bootstrap 5 way or css way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both `.mt-auto` and `.mb-0` to the paragraph. This sets bottom margin to `0` and top margin to `auto` getting as close as possible to the next element below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p class="ms-auto mt-auto mb-0 small">Stupid Text</p>
</div>
<hr class="my-0">
```

Answer (score 0):

use `align-items:baseline` style to d-flex div container

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex" style="align-items:baseline">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p class="ms-auto small">Stupid Text</p>
</div>
<hr class="my-0">
```